# R ggplot2 reduce space between categories in line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
Name    Value   Type
One     500     Confirmed
One     1000    Total
Two     550     Confirmed
Two     900     Total
Three   550     Confirmed
Three   800     Total
```

And the following R script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(ggplot2)

data = structure(list(Name = c("One", "One", "Two", "Two", "Three", 
"Three"), Value = c(500L, 1000L, 550L, 900L, 550L, 800L), Type = c("Confirmed", 
"Total", "Confirmed", "Total", "Confirmed", "Total")), .Names = c("Name", 
"Value", "Type"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Value, y=Name, group=Name, colour=Type)) + geom_line(color="black") + geom_point()
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image: Generated image]

My question is, how can I reduce the vertical space between the three categories (One, Two, Three)? They seem needlessly far apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the aspect-ratio/size of your plot output.

Here is an example that uses your same code:

[image]

Would it be better to have the lines close together, and lots of space to the outside? I doubt it, but if you add

```
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-9,13))
```

to your plot, you can get this:

[image]